# Waiting for bot to be ready after creation in Azure

Tags: azure, botframework

I have been trying to test web app bot creation in Azure so I have been deleting and recreating a particular bot. Here are the settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Creation always succeeds, but on most occasions, when I go to run the Test in Web Chat option I get the perpetual spinning thing says "Waiting for bot to be ready". If I delete the bot and try again with the same settings, it might be fine and work, or it might not with the same waiting message. Any idea what could be going on here? I am trying to teach a class about Bots so it would be nice to be able to create the same bot over and over again and have it work consistently.

Comment: Navigate to the `/api/messages` url, if this gives you error?

Comment: `when I go to run the Test in Web Chat option I get the perpetual spinning thing says "Waiting for bot to be ready".` You can try to connect your bot using Bot Framework Emulator and check if your bot service can work with Emulator. Besides, if "Waiting for bot to be ready" message shows for long time and it could not be ready, you can try to create [support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known timing issue with portal backend communicating with the portal UI.

Sometimes the provisioning completes, but the **Web Chat** control cannot be used because the resources are not fully loaded.  In this state, **'Test in Web Chat'** can hang and not complete.  As a workaround, clicking off of **'Test in Web Chat'** (click on **'Channels'** or **'Settings'**), then back onto **'Test in Web Chat'** will 'Revive' the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the below option in Publish settings under Configuration settings and then republish your bot

[image]