# Test in WebChat window keep shows "waiting for bot to be ready"

Tags: botframework

I create azure bot with C# SDK and Echo Bot option. As there is no option appearing i.e. V3 or V4.
After giving all necessary details and out of the box bot created. Navigate and click the Test in Web Chat, that window keep showing waiting. Even i created the new bot, same issue persist.
Kindly suggest, what's issue here or any workaround.
[image: image 1]

Comment: are you checking the bot right the very next second it is created, give some time and check it, as it is provisioning it, also, if still the error is there, check the app insights , will be will the error/logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for bot to be ready after creation in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899035/waiting-for-bot-to-be-ready-after-creation-in-azure)