# Direct Channel Bot Publishing Issue (bot framework V4)

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I'm using Bot Framework V4, C#, .NET Core 2.2 and VS 2019 to publish my application on Azure.

The bot works well via bot emulator on both local and remote instances.
Hence I believe the application is fine from an authentication/authorization perspective.

However, it doesn’t work via Azure 'Test in Web Chat' module.

All typed messages get a:

> ‘Send failed. Retry.’

reply. The error message logged in the Channels module is:

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError.

What could be wrong?

[image: Autentication code snippet]

[image: Authentication variables result]

Comment: Can you share your botHandle(Display Name in the Settings for the bot)? Also, are you have issues only in 'Test in Web Chat' or any other channel as well? When you test in web chat, can you check if you get any errors in the console of the Chrome Dev Tools(Ctrl+Shift+I)?Do you have Application Insights configured for your bot?

Comment: Display Name: V4BellaConverse
Messaging endpoint: https://v4bellaconverse.azurewebsites.net/api/messages . I'm also having issues while running it via Direct Channel.
Application insights has just been activated.
Now observing the Chrome Dev Tool the following error called my attention.
`[Microsoft_Azure_BotService]  1:27:27 PM MsPortalFx/Base/Base.Net Base.Net: Security issue: Request to send auth token to untrusted domain 'v4bellaconverse.scm.azurewebsites.net'. Only a fixed set of domains should be configured to receive auth tokens.`
It seems there is an authorization issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you check your botHandle(in the bot settings) again? I can't see any logs or data for 'V4BellaConverse'.

Comment: Thx. I've posted an screenshot of the botHandle at https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htscpHfyydazWPfZQYqg

Comment: On the log point I can see some activities generated via Emulator. More details at https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htscpITNiBoK-Nki3s5w . I've just tried to republish the app and got to following message: `An error occurred while starting the application.
.NET Core 4.6.28008.02 X86 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.2.7-servicing-10089    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393    |   Need help?`

Comment: Thank you for the botHandle. If you go to the Channels tab and click on the "Edit" option for Direct Line, have you enabled the Enhanced authentication options? I just saw your latest comment, how are you trying to publish your app to Azure?

Comment: Thx. I haven't enabled the Direct Line enhanced authentication option.
Regarding the app publishing question I've been using VS 2019 for that.
I've basically created a publishing profile on VS that manages the AppService update.

Comment: I decided to republish the app. This time via Azure. After the App Service has been created I've updated my bot on VS with the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword that has been provided. I've also changed the App Service stack on Azure to .Net Core on Azure. Finally I've published my bot reusing the App Service created by Azure. No worries on the publishing process but when I try to run it via 'Test in Web Chat'  it hangs with the message ' Waiting for bot to be ready'. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you check if the destination URL in Publish settings is https and not http? Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917557/9599453)

Comment: Since you decided to republish the app, Change your publish settings to have Remove additional files at destination checked. This is an important step because when you provisioned a new web app bot, it will already have some files in the location. So when you publish your code, it will be placed along with the code files which already exists. You can also test it by navigating to the /api/messages url. If this gives you error, then this is most likely the case.

Comment: Thx. I've tried your recommendations but it still doesn't work. The destination url is https. Sharing a few pointers that might give us a hint: 1 - Publishing Specs: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htscpLeh3c_ARt4rNzCQ   2- VS publishing message: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htscpJZjnr4ISlBUeF1w   3 - Browser error after publishing: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htscpKpWcmjybvniyJmA

Comment: BTW, after a long time the Test in Web Chat window has opened. However, the bot doesn't reply to inquiries. Thoughts? https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htscpMdb79KlLT4Iw-tw

Comment: Last point: I've found the following error while inspecting the browser diagnostic `Microsoft_Azure_BotService]  10:01:15 AM MsPortalFx/Base/Base.Net Base.Net: Security issue: Request to send auth token to untrusted domain 'v4bellaconverse.scm.azurewebsites.net'. Only a fixed set of domains should be configured to receive auth tokens.` Someone had a simular issue a few months ago but no solution was reported at that time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734184/request-to-send-auth-token-to-untrusted-domain-x-scm-azurewebsites-net-only-a

Comment: The .NET error might be due to various reasons.Try adding ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS = true in app settings of your app, restart it and see the detailed error next time you load the url. That will help you fix the issue.Refer to [this](https://scottsauber.com/2017/04/10/how-to-troubleshoot-an-error-occurred-while-starting-the-application-in-asp-net-core-on-iis/)

Comment: One more way would be to use [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) and then use 'Test in Web Chat' to debug locally. Also,do you have the appid/password in the appsettings and the AppService configuration as well?

Comment: are you still having issues or you were able to resolve it?

Comment: Thanks for Checking.
Still breaking my head unfortunately.
The good news is taht I was able to narrow the problem.
My steps:
1) Created and published an Echo Bot: it worked fine on both Azure and on the emulator!
2) Copied small parts of my code to the new template until I identified the class that crashes the app: it is the Startup.cs
3) Played with Kudu but couldn't find any clue about IIS error dump
4) Also tried ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS = true but aditional info has not been provided after error

Comment: Would you mind looking at my Startup.cs (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htscpRnJ2pHCMubR__2Q) and appsettings (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htscpQzzNSDnn3k7yUog)
Hope you can see what's wrong in the code.

Comment: Sure, would have a look at the code and get back to you. In the meanwhile, can you confirm the botHandle? I tried searching for the bot logs on our end for 'V4BellaConverse' and it shows GatewayTimeout errors.

Comment: GatewayTimeouts happen when the bot is taking more than 15 seconds to respond (i.e.,when the connector calls the bot, it will timeout if the bot does not acknowledge the call with a response within 15 seconds). Timeout exceptions are due to a long running process within the bot's code. A way to start with would be to check if there is a code within the bot which might possibly take more than 15 seconds to process and if does, try making it an asynchronous operation. Also, upgrade to the latest SDK version.

Comment: Thx. The new BotHandle is now x4echobot. You might see some successful transactions due to the Echobot mode. Now it's not working given I switched it back to my application mode. However, I can switch it on and off  as needed. Thanks for the hint about the gateway timeout. Yes, I do have a startup procedure in my code that access a SQL DB when the app starts. However, it's quick when running from the emulator. I was wondering if Azure is blocking or retarding the DB access for any reason.

Comment: Here is my connection string: `Data Source= ainetworksprod.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=BellaEduSuite; Pooling=True; Min Pool Size=25; Max Pool Size=500; Persist Security Info=False; User ID = ***; Password = ****;`

Comment: Regarding SDK updates, I've updated the suite to:
Visual Studio Community 2019 16.3.6,
Development Tools plus .NET Core 2.1,
Web Development Tools plus .NET Core 2.1. Nuget packages are all up-to-date. No luck with the publishing issue though.

Comment: I had a look at your Startup.cs file and looks like you are still using bot files(which have been deprecated from 4.3 onward). Its either  your startup.cs files is not able to find the bot file correctly or if you have created two apps(app service and bot channels registration), you might have  missed putting the app id and password into the app services, from the Bot Channels Registration on azure

Comment: Have a look at this documentation to manage bot resources https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-file-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: let us continue our discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201511/ranusharao)

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.
You were spot on!
Everything is working after the bot files have been migrated the appsettings.
Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: glad to hear that your issue got resolved. I have posted it as an answer. Can you please accept and up vote it so that it helps others? Thanks

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Done. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this so that it helps others.

After having a look at your Startup.cs file, it appears that you are making use of bot files.

> Prior to the Bot Framework SDK 4.3 release, Microsoft Botframework offered the .bot file as a mechanism to manage resources. However, going forward we recommend that you use appsettings.json or .env file for managing these resources. Bots that use .bot file will continue to work for now even though the .bot file has been deprecated.

It is always recommended to migrate the settings from .bot files to better manage resources. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-file-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) documentation clearly explains on how to migrate settings from .bot file to manage resources.